# Column Space, Row Space, Null Space are Subspaces of...?

Tags: linear-algebra

For an m x n Matrix

- Column space spans R^m
- Row space spans R^n
- Null space spans R^n

If the dimension of Row space and Null space are not the same

Such as a 4 x 6 matrix of rank 2

- dim column space = 2
- dim row space = 2
- dim null space = 4

How could both row space of A and null space of A span R^n if they don't have the same dimension?

Comment: The matrix $A$ gives a map from $\Bbb R^m\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$. For $m=4$, and nullspace of dimension $4$, this means $A=0$. So the row space cannot be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A  \epsilon  F^{m×n}$
Then null space of $A$ contains those vectors $x$ from $F^n$ that satisfy $Ax=0$ . The dimension of vectors in null space is less than or equal to $n$. So if you span a space from vectors in null space that will have dimension ≤ n .( Not $= n$ as you have mentioned).
Even as you have mentioned in your example $m=4$ & $n=6$ but $dim(col) ≤2 $ which in not equal to $m$ i.e. span of columns is not $R^m$ (similarly for row space & null space )as your assertion says.
So conclusion is $N(A) ≤ F^n$ . The notation represents subspace & they are not equal.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.